# Read/Write FIFO in TCL and C, garbage output

Tags: c, tcl, readfile, fifo

I am trying to establish a connection between TCL script and C code.

**here is the TCL script**

```
set fs[open "./fifo_server" "w"]
puts $fs "level_3"
flush $fs
```

**here is the C code**

```
if ((fs = fopen ("./fifo_server", "r"))== NULL)
    perror ("error occured while opening FIFO_SERVER");
  else {
    fs1 = fileno(fs);
    read(fs1, in_data, sizeof(in_data));
  }
  printf ("in_data = %s\n", in_data);
```

**The output looks like:**

```
in_data = level_3
(some garbage stuff 5 spaces which contains Question marks, Squares, 
Characters etc.)
```

I don't understand, what could be the reason for the garbage line ???

appreciate your precise and earlier help.

thanks and Regards, 
M.

Comment: For one use `set fs [open "./fifo_server" "w"]` instead. Spaces matter in Tcl.

Comment: Why are you using `fileno` and `read` instead of `fread`? Or, conversely, `fopen` instead of `open`? Try to avoid using two APIs for the one file descriptor/handle…

Comment: @Jerry I think that must be a transcription error or the code would never have worked as much as it is reported to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as Jerry pointed out, you need a space between the variable `fs` and the square bracket:

```
set fs [open "./fifo_server" "w"]
```

I don't know the reason why you read file in such a low-level manner (i.e. using file number, instead of the FILE* handle). However, you will need to terminate your string yourself since `read()` does not automatically do so:

```
int chars_read; /* How many chars read from a file */

if ((fs = fopen ("./fifo_server", "r")) == NULL)
    perror ("error occured while opening FIFO_SERVER");
else {
    fs1 = fileno(fs);
    chars_read = read(fs1, in_data, sizeof(in_data));
    in_data[chars_read] = '\0'; /* terminate your string */
}
printf ("in_data = %s\n", in_data);
```

Comment: That looks like the problem to me, as all the expected bytes are also there *before* the junk. Classic overrun symptom.

Comment: I don't think this is an overrun problem. `read()` and `fread()` are designed to read raw data. At such, they won't NULL-terminate your buffer.

Comment: No; the overrun happens in the `printf()` because the data is unterminated. It's not the fault of `read()` at all, which is doing what it is documented to do.